# Saving user input in json file

Tags: javascript, html, json

So i have a HTML page that asks the user the name, the description and the image of an activity (like a formular). I want to make a function that saves all the user input into the data.json file when the user clicks on the button but i don't know how to do it. Here the function about the button in js :

```
function send() {
var nomActi = document.getElementById("nomActi").value;
var descriActi = document.getElementById("descriActi").value;
var imageActi = document.getElementById("imageActi").value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres how you can write to a json file.

`fs` - module to write it to a file

```js
const fs = require('fs');

// create a JSON object
const user = {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 22
};

// convert JSON object to string
const data = JSON.stringify(user);

// write JSON string to a file
fs.writeFile('user.json', data, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("JSON data is saved.");
});
```